# Why "objectionable" and not "objectable"?

Tags: etymology

"Objectionable" is strange because unlike most "-able" words it begins with a noun instead of a verb.

I would think it should be "objectable", ie, capable of being objected to.

What is the reason for it being "objectionable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the suffix -able is added to verbs to form adjectives, and objection, originally, comes from a past participle:

***[Objectionable](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=objectionable) (adj.):***

> - 1781, from [objection](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=objection&allowed_in_frame=0)+ -[able](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-able&allowed_in_frame=0). Related: Objectionably.

***objection (n.)***

> - late 14c., from Old French objeccion "reply, retort" (12c.) and directly from Late Latin obiectionem (nominative obiectio), "a throwing or putting before," ***noun of action from past participle stem of Latin obicere "to oppose" (see object (n.)).***

***-able:***

> - ***word-forming element expressing ability, capacity, fitness, from French, from Latin -ibilis, -abilis, forming adjectives from verbs,*** properly -bilis (the vowels being generally from the stem of the word being suffixed.

(Etymonline)

As you can see from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=objectionable%2Cobjectable&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cobjectionable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cobjectable%3B%2Cc0), [objectable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objectable) usage has always been uncommon.

Comment: Ah, that explains it perfectly. Objection actually is a verb!

Answer (score 0):

> **objectionable** : arousing distaste or opposition; unpleasant or offensive. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/objectionable
>
> **objectable**: 
>        Such as can be presented in opposition; that may be put forward as an objection. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Objectable

"Objectable" if googled will get some hits, but if you look at it on merriam webster http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objectable it's considered archaic, though it is was word but is not used anymore. 
The words have two different meanings.

> Ex: When teenagers use vulgar language it is considered objectionable.

Comment: Is it *not* considered objectionable when people younger or older than teenagers use vulgar language?